# How to start the TabBarController after a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've a loginViewController and on successful login I want to start the app by showing the home screen which has a parent tab bar.[image]

The current process I'm using is:

```
UITabBarController *arvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeVC"];

    [self presentViewController:arvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But it dosen't load the tab bar below the screen. So How to achieve it.

Comment: you want to navigate you app to tab bar cont after success login ?

Comment: @vaibhav yes that is correct.

Comment: why dont you make TabBarController As Initial Controller ? In View Did load of `TabBarController` check that if user is not logged in then present LoginViewController. When user get logged in successfully then dismiss it.

Comment: @TalhaCh see my ans below and let me know ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `storyboard`, From your loginviewController `ctrl+drag` to your `UITabbarController` and select `show` from `popup`. It will create new `show` segue from your login view controller to tabbarcontroller. then select that `segue` by clicking on it and from `attribute inspector` set it `identifier` like `pushToTabbarController` or whatever identifier you want to keep.

Now when you successfully login and when want to  go to tabbbarviewcontroller then you just need to call,

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToTabbarController" sender:nil];  //identifier that you have set in Interface builder
```

Comment: I'm only getting three options on `ctrl+drag` those are `push` `modal` and `custom` and If I I only put the line of code in login success it give me an error `Receiver has no segue with identifier`

Comment: `ctrl + drag` from `loginviewcontroller` to your `tabbarviewcontroller` and you will see `show`. You should drag from `yellow square available in your viewcontroller on top`

Comment: once you will set this segue and give proper identifier and will use that identifier in `performSegueWithIdentifier` method, you will not get `Receiver has no segue with identifier` error!!

Comment: After dragging from yellow box I got the same options but after I selected `modal` and then I selected the connection arrow of modal and gave it an identifier and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] init];

   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

---

```
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate you app after successful login using below code. Method `presentViewController` will update the hirachary of `viewcontrollers` and current `viewController` will become `rootViewController` ..

you must give `identity` to your `tabBarController` using `Identity Inspector` on storyboard see image.

[image]

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerName"];
// this will update viewcontroller stack and vc will become top viewController
[self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```